# Map collections in ES-2015 wtih an Error on loop output

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I'm tring to undertand how the algoritms of `Map` collections work in ES-2015, but when I work with `Map` methods I got a strange situation with variables `a` and `b` about **missing ")"** in the function loop end.

Anyone know what is can be the problem?

```js
'use strict';

let map = new Map([
  ['1',  'str1'],
  [1,    'num1'],
  [true, 'bool1']
]);


map.forEach((value, key, map) => {
  let a = `${value}`.split(',')[0];
  let b = `${value}`.split(',')[1];
  console.log( a ':' b ); // got an error "SyntaxError: missing )
})                        // after argument list"
```

Comment: Note that the single line `console.log(1 ':' 2)` raises the exact same error for the exact same reason without all the extra code.

Comment: @OP Please do not add `Solved` to your title. See this meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-cant-i-mark-my-title-as-solved

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Such a stupid and banal mistake. Probably it was a hard day for me today :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you wanted to print `Key:Value` in the console for every key value pair in the Map. Just fixing the `console.log` will work but since you are learning about `Map` I am adding on why a Map is more suitable than a Javascript plain object for the input you want.

When you provide 2D array like that to `Map` it creates an ES6 Map which looks something like `{'1': 'str1', 1: 'num1', true: 'bool1'}`

Now the difference between creating an ES6 map vs a plain Javascript object is that the keys retain their provided data type in `Map`.

Object usually treats all the keys as strings, so when you provide an entry with `"1"` and `1` which are `String` and `Number`, object will treat both of them as `"1"` and assigns the recently given value to either `"1"` or `1`.

```
let object = {'1': 'str1', 1: 'num1', true: 'bool1'}
console.log(object);
// {1: "num1", true: "bool1"}
```

While the map you created will be created something like this

```
Map(3) {"1" => "str1", 1 => "num1", true => "bool1"}
```

```js
'use strict';

let map = new Map([
  ['1',  'str1'],
  [1,    'num1'],
  [true, 'bool1']
]);


map.forEach((value, key, set) => {
  console.log( key + ':' + value ); 
})

let object = {'1': 'str1', 1: 'num1', true: 'bool1'}

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive response!

Answer (score 4):

The syntax inside of your console.log isn't valid use `console.log(a, ':', b)` or `console.log(a + ':' + b)`